# Mozila Crash Reporter message

Tags: firefox

I'm getting this message in multi messages tabs:

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this?

The full log is:

```
AdapterDeviceID: 0x1912
AdapterDriverVersion: 30.0.101.1339
AdapterSubsysID: 00000000
AdapterVendorID: 0x8086
AvailablePageFile: 29040738304
AvailablePhysicalMemory: 25129594880
AvailableVirtualMemory: 138522893692928
BackgroundTaskMode: 1
BackgroundTaskName: backgroundupdate
BlockedDllList: 
BuildID: 20220922185808
CPUMicrocodeVersion: 0xcc
ContentSandboxCapable: 1
ContentSandboxLevel: 6
CrashTime: 1664421012
HeadlessMode: 1
InstallTime: 1663944147
LauncherProcessState: 0
ModuleSignatureInfo: {"Microsoft Corporation":["VCRUNTIME140.dll","VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","msvcp140.dll"],"Microsoft Windows":["ondemandconnroutehelper.dll","wscapi.dll","twinapi.dll","wininet.dll","winrnr.dll","wshbth.dll","pnrpnsp.dll","NapiNSP.dll","Windows.Globalization.dll","DWrite.dll","ktmw32.dll","dbgcore.dll","winmm.dll","dbghelp.dll","urlmon.dll","webauthn.dll","Windows.UI.Immersive.dll","iertutil.dll","icm32.dll","BCP47mrm.dll","ColorAdapterClient.dll","rasadhlp.dll","mscms.dll","InputHost.dll","Windows.UI.dll","TextInputFramework.dll","npmproxy.dll","Bcp47Langs.dll","twinapi.appcore.dll","WindowManagementAPI.dll","FWPUCLNT.DLL","winhttp.dll","srvcli.dll","dhcpcsvc.dll","dhcpcsvc6.DLL","winnsi.dll","version.dll","wsock32.dll","netprofm.dll","nlaapi.dll","propsys.dll","wtsapi32.dll","WinTypes.dll","dcomp.dll","CoreUIComponents.dll","CoreMessaging.dll","uxtheme.dll","dwmapi.dll","kernel.appcore.dll","windows.storage.dll","dxgi.dll","ntmarta.dll","IPHLPAPI.DLL","dnsapi.dll","netutils.dll","mswsock.dll","cryptbase.dll","wldp.dll","ntasn1.dll","ncrypt.dll","msasn1.dll","devobj.dll","winsta.dll","sspicli.dll","userenv.dll","profapi.dll","KERNELBASE.dll","cfgmgr32.dll","bcrypt.dll","crypt32.dll","win32u.dll","gdi32full.dll","ucrtbase.dll","wintrust.dll","msvcp_win.dll","bcryptPrimitives.dll","shlwapi.dll","nsi.dll","psapi.dll","oleaut32.dll","sechost.dll","gdi32.dll","imm32.dll","setupapi.dll","msvcrt.dll","kernel32.dll","ws2_32.dll","ole32.dll","msctf.dll","shell32.dll","SHCore.dll","advapi32.dll","combase.dll","user32.dll","clbcatq.dll","rpcrt4.dll","ntdll.dll"],"Mozilla Corporation":["firefox.exe","xul.dll","nss3.dll","freebl3.dll","mozglue.dll","nssckbi.dll","osclientcerts.dll","softokn3.dll","lgpllibs.dll"]}
MozCrashReason: Shutdown hanging at step XPCOMShutdownThreads. Something is blocking the main-thread.
Notes: FP(D00-L1000-W00001000-T000) 
DWrite? DWrite+ WR? WR+ 
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: aurora
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 50401
ShutdownProgress: xpcom-shutdown-threads
StartupCrash: 0
StartupTime: 1664420940
SubmittedFrom: Client
SystemMemoryUsePercentage: 26
Throttleable: 1
TotalPageFile: 39441178624
TotalPhysicalMemory: 34224513024
TotalVirtualMemory: 140737488224256
URL: 
UptimeTS: 723.85747
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 106.0
Winsock_LSP: MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IP] : 2 : 2 : 1 : 6 : 0x20066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : e70f1aa0-ab8b-11cf-8ca3-00805f48a192 
 MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IP] : 2 : 2 : 2 : 17 : 0x20609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : e70f1aa0-ab8b-11cf-8ca3-00805f48a192 
 MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IP] : 2 : 2 : 3 : 0 : 0x20609 : 0xc : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : e70f1aa0-ab8b-11cf-8ca3-00805f48a192 
 MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IPv6] : 2 : 23 : 1 : 6 : 0x20066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : f9eab0c0-26d4-11d0-bbbf-00aa006c34e4 
 MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IPv6] : 2 : 23 : 2 : 17 : 0x20609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : f9eab0c0-26d4-11d0-bbbf-00aa006c34e4 
 MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IPv6] : 2 : 23 : 3 : 0 : 0x20609 : 0xc : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : f9eab0c0-26d4-11d0-bbbf-00aa006c34e4 
 AF_UNIX : 2 : 1 : 1 : 0 : 0x20026 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : a00943d9-9c2e-4633-9b59-0057a3160994 
 RSVP TCPv6 Service Provider : 2 : 23 : 1 : 6 : 0x22066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 RSVP TCP Service Provider : 2 : 2 : 1 : 6 : 0x22066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 RSVP UDPv6 Service Provider : 2 : 23 : 2 : 17 : 0x22609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 RSVP UDP Service Provider : 2 : 2 : 2 : 17 : 0x22609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 Hyper-V RAW : 2 : 34 : 1 : 1 : 0x20026 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 1234191b-4bf7-4ca7-86e0-dfd7c32b5445 
 MSAFD L2CAP [Bluetooth] : 2 : 32 : 1 : 256 : 0x20006 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9fc48064-7298-43e4-b7bd-181f2089792a 
 MSAFD RfComm [Bluetooth] : 2 : 32 : 1 : 3 : 0x20026 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9fc48064-7298-43e4-b7bd-181f2089792a
XPCOMSpinEventLoopStack: default: nsThread::Shutdown: BitsCommander
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

Comment: Aurora is/was for alpha and beta builds. Are you running a GA version from the release channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Firefox Developer Edition (Aurora) Channel,
which is meant for developers that can well analyze and report
problems to Mozilla. Being on that channel means that you are ready
to become an alpha tester and to suffer problems in order to help the
Firefox team vet their software.

If you wish a stable Firefox version that has been extensively tested,
you should return to the Release Channel (the default).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that.